# On improving the regularity of solutions to nonlinear parabolic pde

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, parabolic-pde, flows

There's a common reasoning i have seen in many papers/books that work with parabolic pde's (most specifically in the context of geometric flows) but I can't fully grasp it. This reasoning is that to improve the regularity of a solution (once we have a priori estimates) we can differentiate the pde and check that the derivatives solve a linear parabolic pde therefore are bounded. My question is related to the fact that I'm not sure we can always conclude that bound. More info below

**The setting**

Let's say we have the following nonlinear parabolic pde (let's work with one spatial dimension to make it simpler):

$$\partial_t u= F(u,\partial_x u,\partial_x^2u)$$
$$u(\cdot,0)=u_0$$

defined over $M\times [0,T)$ with $M$ a compact set (in my case it's $S^1$, but it shouldn't make much of a difference). Let $F$ be sufficiently smooth and the derivative on the $\partial_x^2 u$ coordinate is bounded above zero (i.e. the equation is parabolic). Also the initial data $u_0$ is of class $C^\infty$.

I have already proven an uniform $C^{2+\alpha,1+\alpha/2}(M\times[0,T))$ a priori estimate, then i used that to prove short time existence in $C^\infty(M\times[0,T))$.

I can then prove long time existence in $C^{2+\alpha,1+\alpha/2}(M\times[0,\infty))$ with the usual reasoning by contradiction, i.e. let's say the solution has a maximum time of existence but since we have the estimates from before we know that the $C^{2+\alpha,1+\alpha/2}(M\times[0,T))$ norm doesn't blow up so we can extend the solution contradicting the maximum time of existence.

If i could prove uniform estimates over higher order derivatives of $u$ i could then use the same contradiction reasoning to prove that the solution is of class $C^\infty(M\times[0,\infty))$. The problem i have is with how people prove the estimates over higher order derivatives of $u$.

**The usual reasoning**

What i usually see that people do to bound the higher order derivatives of $u$ is an induction argument like the following:

Let $w_{k,l}:=\partial_x^k\partial_t^l u$, let's prove that $w_{k,l}$ is bounded by induction first over $k$ then over $l$, applying $\partial_k\partial_l$ to our original pde for $u$ we get something like:

\begin{align}
\partial_t w_{k,l}=& f(w_{k,l})\\
&+\text{something bounded} \cdot \partial_x w_{k,l}\\
&+\text{something positive and bounded }\cdot\partial_x^2 w_{k,l} 
\end{align}

Where $f(w_{k,l})$ is a function that only depends on $w_{k,l}$ and derivatives of lower order. Then they note that this is a linear parabolic pde so that implies $w_{k,l}$ is bounded.

**My question**

Is it true that ($w_{k,l}$ solves a linear parabolic pde) $\Rightarrow$ ($w_{k,l}$ bounded) in this case?

As far as I know the comparison principle gives us an estimate of the form
$$\dfrac{d^+ {w_{k,l}}_+}{dt^+}\leq f({w_{k,l}}_+)$$
where ${w_{k,l}}_+(t)=\text{sup}_{x\in M}w_{k,l}(x,t)$ and $\frac{d^+}{dt^+}$ is a one sided derivative. This means that to conclude that $w_{k,l}$ is bounded we would need to know that $f(x)$ has at most linear growth, so we could use Grönwall's inequality, but they don't check that. It could be that $f(x)=x^2$ or something and we would get that $w_{k,l}$ could blow up in finite time, i.e. not be bounded.

I ask this because i have checked by hand a few times and the terms of lower order do grow cuadratically or even faster so I'm not sure if that is enough to get the bound.

Any help would be much appeciated.

**References**

Claus Gerhardt. Curvature Problems. Series in Geometry and Topology. International Press
of Boston, Somerville, MA, 2007. Chapter 2.7.

Benjamin Meco. Expanding flows of curves in the hyperbolic plane.